# If $G(s)=G(p+qs)e^{\lambda(s-1)}$ then $G(s)=e^{\lambda(s-1)/p}$

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions

> If $G_{n+1}=G_n=G$ where $G(s)=G(p+qs)e^{\lambda(s-1)}$, how can one conclude that $G(s)=e^{\lambda(s-1)/p}$

the G's above are generating functions, In this exercise one has independent variables $X_n$ geometric distributed, and writes it as sum of Bernoulli variables, $X_{n+1}=\sum_1^{X_n}B_i+Y_n$ (the factor $e^{\lambda(s-1)}$ comes from the r.v. Y_n. which is Poisson distributed) then every $X_i$ has generating function $p+qs$ and in search of a stationary distribution, one sets $G_{n+1}=G_n=G$, but I don't understand the conclusion.

Comment: Hint: $g(t)=G(1-t)$ is such that $g(t)=g(qt)e^{-\lambda t}$ for every $t$ in $[0,1]$ hence $g(t)=e^{-\lambda(1-q^n)t/(1-q)}g(q^nt)$ for every $n$ and $g(t)\to$ $__$ when $t\to0$ hence $g(q^nt)\to$ $___$ when $n\to\infty$ hence $g(t)=$ $___$ for every $t$ in $[0,1]$, QED.

Comment: @Did Awesome Did, thanks a lot